# how to get web address of email service from an email address

Tags: email, dns

how to get web address of email service from an email address?

Most of times we can split email address by @ character and get the last part and plus "mail.", but sometimes for example abc@hotmail.com, it's not right. My purpose is to get the complete email server address http url such as "http://mail.gmail.com/"

Could someone tell me how to get the correct web address of email service from email address ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How could abc@hotmail.com not be correct?  When you split on the `@` it will always split correctly.  Email addresses will never have more than one `@`.  Can you post some code?

Comment: You *cannot* get web address to a mail service from the email address because they are completely independent of each other.

Comment: @bala-r thank you. you said is my meaning. if i can not get it from email address, how can i redirect to go to user's mail box from his email? but many website has this feature.

Comment: i think you need to create a database of email-hosts and their web-mail-address. than you can can create the links to the webmail. of course that will work only for some of the users/emails

Comment: @daniel-kutik yes, you're right and i thought. but i can not get the collection of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look up the [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for the domain to find out the details of the mail servers for that domain. This is part of the [Domain Name System (DNS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Here is an interactive tool that does this: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

On Unix, you could use `dig`:

```
aix@aix:~$ dig google.com MX

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     589 IN  MX  40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     589 IN  MX  50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     589 IN  MX  10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     589 IN  MX  20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     589 IN  MX  30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: thank you, but that's not i want. from the mx records i don't know the domain access url is "http://hostmail.com" or "http://mail.hotmail.com".

Comment: @ywenbo: What exactly do you mean by "the domain access url"?

Comment: it's web address of email service.

Comment: he has an email address and wants to get the url of it's web mail interface.